# Will the command "hadoop namenode -format" change the whole hard disk filesystem type?

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs, kvm

My hadoop is built on KVM environment, but the VMs are not only for hadoop distributed computing, they have other important tasks.

So, I'm wondering whether the command `hadoop namenode -format` will format the VMs's whole hard disk to HDFS type and make the VM's other job crash...

By the way, is there any resource about HDFS ? I'll appreciate the flavor very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HDFS isn't a real file system that runs on your hard drive like ext3 or something similar, it is close to database. Just like a database, HDFS stores data on a regular file system and provides an API to access its data.

So don't worry about corrupting your data outside Hadoop with "hadoop namenode -format", this command just initialize the "database".

You can read about HDFS in a book "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide", also you may make the acquaintance with HDFS with this article - http://www.aosabook.org/en/hdfs.html

Comment: thank you very much. I've accomplish the hadoop configration as you said. The hadoop is very considerate, so are you. thx again~